# How I should parse this type of bytes?

Tags: python, string, byte, decode, python-3.7

I have the following type of bytes:

```
b = b'2787\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96\x08\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0047\x00>2!\tMV\xa7\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I must convert it to a string and obtain the 2787, how I should strip the \x00 values,
I just tryed with decode("utf-8") but throws the follwing error message:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 33: invalid start byte

Also rstrip('\x00) didn't work.

Which type of decode I should use?

I obtain a list of strings from here:

```
data, addr = socket_udp.recvfrom(struct.calcsize("B13s9s61s"))
info = struct.unpack("B13s9s61s", data)
```

And b is the last 61 string.
The content of the string:

```
class Udp_packet:
type = 0x00
id  = ""
random_num = ""
data = ""


def __init__(self, values_list, convert=False):       
    self.type       = values_list[0]
    self.id         = values_list[1]
    self.random_num = values_list[2]
    self.data       = values_list[3].split("\0")[0]
```

The code works properly using python 2.7, I just moved to 3.7.5

Comment: how is this string being generated

Comment: @gold_cy I receive it throw a socket.

Comment: What's that string supposed to be? Out of those 13 starting bytes, which ones are relevant? Do you have some formatting specs?

Comment: @CristiFati Is just additional data used in the communiation, the problem is that the last string longitude is not always 61s.

Comment: Another option you have there is using list comprehension and iterating over the bytes. Not sure if it can help you stripping the `\x00`.
Something like: `''.join([b for b in bytes if b != b'\x00'])` maybe will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want from `b` is apparently the portion before the first NUL byte, `b'\x00'`, or simply `b'\0'`, so you can slice `b` by the the index of the first NUL byte:

```
b = b[:b.find(b'\0')]
```